# Sherpa: браузер и его вкладки стали падать

Tags: c#

Спустя месяц после последнего удачного запуска Sherpa RPA перестала корректно работать на всех роботах, где есть Chrome. В частности цикл смены поисковых запросов ломается. Выдает одну и ту же ошибку:

```
ERROR: Не удалось найти процесс с именем "chrome". Убедитесь, что имя процесса введено правильно, и повторите вызов командлета.
```

Браузер установлен, пользователей на нем удалили, пробовали вкладкой инкогнито, результат тот же.

Как быть? Куда вешать логи? до вхождения в цикл робот работает корректно.

Comment: Наверное связываться с ними, хотя на офф.сайте никакого намёка на поддержку не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

Помогает перезагрузка Win.

Саппорт посоветовал переустановить браузерное расширение Sherpa.

"Для работы плагина в хроме нужно выполнить все эти действия:

Все шаги от учетки робота

1. Запускаем хром, если там есть расширение шерпы, удаляем. Устанавливаем свитч "Режим разработчика" в расширениях браузера. Закрываем хром.
2. Открываем хром. Идем в раздел "Расширения". Правой кнопкой по ярлыку  программы "Sherpa Assistant.lnk" с рабочего стола - идем в папку с программой.  Переходим в папку Chrome.
3. Перетаскиваем файл plugin.crx в окно хрома. Добавляем расширение. Отключаем режим разработчика.
4. В папке запускаем install_host.bat.
5. Закрываем браузер

Далее учтите, что плагин должен стоять только в одном браузере, нельзя его одновременно использовать в двух браузерах, например хроме и яндексе. Для работы плагина важен пункт 4, он прописывает в реестре информацию о программе хост, которую запускает браузер при старте. Эта программа работает с плагином и является промежуточным звеном между роботом и хромом. Если программа хост не запускается (а это процесс ProcessAgentHost.exe), то в реестре слетели настройки (которые этот файл bat заносит из пункта 4) и нужно еще раз его запустить. Слететь настройки могут например изза работы групповых политик, которые очищают плагины в хроме, таким образом якобы удаляя вредоносные плагины".